# Different way to say "Courtesy of"

Tags: phrases

Is there some other way to say, "courtesy of"? Let's say that person X gave me a dress; I would like to know a different, rather unique way to say that the dress came to me "courtesy of X". Can someone help?

Comment: Actually, if you were speaking I hope you'd say something like "Jane Smith gave me this dress."  "Courtesy of" is very cold.

Comment: You only say “*courtesy of*” when whatever it is was done ***as a courtesy***.  If your friend have you a dress because she likes you it was probably not done as a courtesy.  But you might try replacing *courtesy of* with ***thanks to***   “*I have this dress **thanks to** my dear friend Shadow.*

Comment: But be careful because *thanks to* can also be used sarcastically  so you must make sure the context in which you use it allow the listener/reader to understand your intent.

Answer (score 2):

The equivalent would be "Compliments of ...". That is, it has been provided by or through the auspices of the gift giver.

Your may say "By the kindness of..." or "Thanks to the kindness of..."

It is not too likely that "Thanks to... " will be misinterpreted as sarcasm but we do not know where you are or who you are talking to.

Comment: Another option would be to use the phrase "through the generosity of"—that sounds appreciative.